# Response to Soap with logicApp

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I receive a Message from Salesforce which is In the form of a Soap Message. I
need to send an acknowledgment back. Here I want to use the LogicApp.
As of now, I kept the APIM in front of my logic app, then

[image]

I am not sure what should I send as it's a Soap call. What I also did is tried to create a more responsive one with the help of SoapUI. Is there a way to respond via LogicApp to Soap action?
This I have done with a WSDL:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of now Soap and REST WSDL generated custom connectors for soap is not supported.

below is the code for Logic App SOAP Pass-through Custom Connector

```
"actions": {
     "SoapPassThrough": {
         "inputs": {
             "body": "<Envelope xmlns=\"https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><Body><GetOrder xmlns:xsi=\"https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"https://tempuri.org/\"><orderId>2468</orderId></GetOrder></Body></Envelope>",
             "headers": {
                 "Content-Type": "text/xml",
                 "SOAPAction": "https://tempuri.org/IFazioService/GetOrder"
             },
```

Some basic troubleshooting:

- "statusCode": 415, aka UnsupportedMediaType -> you need to add the HTTP headers in code view to specify Content-Type as text/xml
- "statusCode": 400, aka BadRequest -> Could be that the HTTP header SOAP action mismatches with the body SOAP envelop payload. Could be that the XML in the payload is malformed.
- "statusCode": 500, aka Internal Server Error, Logic App automatically retries and the response output mentions the gateway service -> Could be that the on-premises SOAP service is offline hence the gateway couldn't call it.

Check [SOAP Pass-through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/david_burgs_blog/logic-app-soap-pass-through-custom-connector) for further information.

Also check how to pass [SOAP](http://twocents.nl/?p=1998) via Logic App.

Here is the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32561458) thread with same discussion.