# Hello, How can I read the content of an XML file and store It in a string variable in Logic App?

Tags: xml, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

How can I read the content of an XML file template containing order information and store it in a string variable that can be submitted to the SOAP endpoint as string in Azure Logic App ?

I know that I can use read content of a file from OneDrive or Sharepoint but in my case I will receive the data as JSON thru en HTTP enpoint that I need to convert to XML and forward to SOAP endpoint as string. I apologize if I don't give much detail as this is my first time asking a question here.

In PHP you can use these methods but I need to create it in Logic app.

**Get the content of the xml file**
$file = fopen('Order.xml','r')
$NewOrder = stream_gt_content($file);

The actions I need to create:
1- Convert JSON to XML according to the template-  **I know roughly how to do it but open to any suggestions**
2- Read the XML file content and store it in variable of type string -  **I need help here**
3- Submit the string to the Soap Endpoint-  **I know roughly how to do it but open to any suggestions**

**The Body of Post call for submitting the string:**
The endpoint expecting the order as string

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
     <addOrderSoapIn>
       <id></id>
       <xml>string</xml>
     </addOrderSoapIn>
   </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

I tried to create a variable with a Type string and value that containes the XML file.
It didn't worked.
[Set variable to store the det XML data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce0Di.png)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the JSON you're wanting to convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is something that you can try to achieve your requirement. Firstly I have used Http request trigger where I will be getting the json data from. Then I have converted the json to xml using below expression.

```
xml(json(triggerBody()))
```

Below is the flow in my logic app.

[image]

For the next step, you can use either of the ways as alternatives for @NandanMathure's answer.

1. Use [custom connector](https://www.sikich.com/insight/how-to-use-soap-pass-through-with-logic-apps-custom-connector/)  explained Justin Languirand for SOAP Api.
2. Use Http action as mentioned in this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542982/can-i-make-a-soap-api-call-in-azure-logic-app).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to call SOAP Service from REST/WebAPI Front End. You can do this in Logic App, but it's more elegant to do it in Azure APIM. Check this article from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/restify-soap-api.

If you need to do it in LogicApp
Understand.

1. Get your SOAP Request working in SOAP UI
2. Add HTTP Activity to your LogicApp.
3. Copy Body actual Body from SOAP UI (Make sure you copy from RAW Tab)
4. Replace the placeholders like in example below
   '''
   @{triggerBody()?['firstName']}@{triggerBody()?['lastName']}
   '''
5. Add Header for SOAPAction, you should get value of this in RAW
6. Configure Content-Type Header

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello Nandan, due to time press, I would need to continue with Logic App Solution. Can the Logic app read XML content and store it on a string type of variable that can be sent to the Soap endpoint? Could you please give an example?

Comment: Enhanced the answer.